# Password error when installing Wordpress in webmatrix

Tags: wordpress, webmatrix

I'm installing webmatrix3 on my system and I want to access wordpress in it. For that I use:

```
   new -> app gallery -> wordpress
```

Another page shows "*What type of database would you like to use?*" and by default Mysql is selected and a password is asked for. What do I put here?

I've tried many passwords but it always shows "*The specified password for the user account is not valid or db cannot connect,*" I didn't put any password in when installing webmatrix.

Answer (score 0):

-double check your wp-config.php file settings for the database name, database username and database password. This is where most errors occur.

-Check that you don't need to change the database host from "localhost" to something else. You can get that info from your hosting provider.

-Check you have actually created a database with the same database name as is in your wp-config.php file.

There are also many threads on this topic on these forums: http://wordpress.org/search/Error+establishing+a+database+connection?forums=1

thank you